# How to speed up this GSL code for selecting a submatrix?

Tags: c++, gsl

I wrote a very simple function in GSL, to select a submatrix from an existing matrix in a struct.

**EDIT: I had timed VERY INCORRECTLY and didn't notice the changed number of zeros in front.Still, I hope this can be sped up**

For 100x100 submatrices of a 10000x10000 matrix, it takes 1.2E-5 seconds. So, repeating that 1E4 times, takes 50 times longer than I need to diagonalise the 100x100 matrix.
EDIT: 
I realise, it happens even if I comment out everything except return(0); 
Thus, I theorize, it must be something about struct TOWER. This is how TOWER looks:

```
struct TOWER 
{
    int array_level[TOWERSIZE];
    int array_window[TOWERSIZE];
    gsl_matrix *matrix_ordered_covariance;
    gsl_matrix *matrix_peano_covariance;

    double array_angle_tw[XISTEP];
    double array_correl_tw[XISTEP]; 
    gsl_interp_accel *acc_correl;   // interpolating for correlation
    gsl_spline *spline_correl;

    double array_all_eigenvalues[TOWERSIZE]; //contains all eiv. of whole matrix

    std::vector< std::vector<double> > cropped_peano_covariance, peano_mask;

};
```

Below comes my function!

```
/* --- --- */
int monolevelsubmatrix(int i, int j, struct TOWER *tower, gsl_matrix *result)  //relying on spline!! //must addd auto vanishing
{
    int firstrow, firstcol,mu,nu,a,b;
    double aux, correl;

    firstrow = helix*i;
    firstcol = helix*j;

    gsl_matrix_view Xi = gsl_matrix_submatrix (tower ->matrix_ordered_covariance, firstrow, firstcol, helix, helix);
    gsl_matrix_memcpy (result, &(Xi.matrix));

    return(0);  
}
/* --- --- */
```

Comment: Building GSL now to check...will take a few

Comment: There's no reason for your struct to slow down your program just by existing. How are you timing your code?

Comment: Everything is part of a huge programme. I am trying to produce a small snippet including timing now!

Comment: Have you considered RAM utilization during your test? At first glance, thus far, it appears the code for submatrix is quite simple and shouldn't do much to be so slow...still looking...

Comment: So far as I can see, the gsl_matrix is just a few integers and a couple of pointers, and creating a subview merely fashions a copy of that structure with a few settings indicating where the subview in the source matrix exists...in other words, there's no real work being done to create the subview, so I have the sense the problem you're encountering is not at the moment the subview is being created as you're thinking...it's something else.

Comment: Ok, I'm getting a sense of it here....it could be the gsl_matrix_memcpy. That's not a simple memcpy, it's a cell by cell copy inside a nested for loop of row/column, using indexes to access the raw data. Each cell copy indexes source and data cells with MULTIPLICITY * dest_tda * i + j. What is the type in use, float, double?

Comment: If you MUST copy the matrix, consider looking at the source for copy_source.c at memcpy. It's a very simple loop with OBVIOUS performance optimizations you could easily create yourself. At the least, if you know the source/dest matrix are identical dimensions, you could probably get away with a CRT memcpy of the data member of gls_matrix and speed this up....could be 50 times

Comment: @JVene The gsl_matrix contains doubles. I am just working on creating a minimal working example. I don't want to unnecesssarily torture all of you, because of the absence of such example. 

In my programme, the time only reduces from 0,12 secs to 0.09 secs, if the function is only return(0);

How could I build a submatrix without memcpy?

Comment: See answer....the issue is a grossly unoptimized gls_matrix_memcpy routine. Oh, torture? What is programming anyway? ;)

Comment: @AnthonyVallée-Dubois Thank you very much andd apology. I was doing it 1E4 times. I was measuring incorrectly.

Comment: @Ludi Glad I could help, timing properly is surprisingly hard :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is almost certainly gls_matric_memcpy. The source for that is in copy_source.c, with:

```
    const size_t src_tda = src->tda ;
    const size_t dest_tda = dest->tda ;
    size_t i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < src_size1 ; i++)
      {
        for (j = 0; j < MULTIPLICITY * src_size2; j++)
          {
            dest->data[MULTIPLICITY * dest_tda * i + j] 
              = src->data[MULTIPLICITY * src_tda * i + j];
          }
      }
```

This would be quite slow. Note that gls_matrix_memcpy returns a GLS_ERROR if the matrices are different sizes, so it's very likely the data member could be served with a CRT memcpy on the data members of dest and src.

This loop is very slow. Each cell is derefence through dest & src structs for the data member, and THEN indexed.

You could choose to write a replacement for the library, or write your own personal version of this matrix copy, with something like (untested suggestion code here):

```
unsigned int cellsize = sizeof( src->data[0] ); // just psuedocode here

memcpy( dest->data, src->data, cellsize * src_size1 * src_size2 * MULTIPLICITY )
```

Note that MULTIPLICITY is a define, usually 1 or 2, probably depends on library configuration - might not apply to your usage (if it's 1 )

Now, important caveat....if the source matrix is a subview, then you have to go by rows...that is, a loop of rows in i where crt's memcpy is limited to rows at a time, not the entire matrix as I show above.

In other words, you do have to account for the source matrix geometry from which the subview was taken...that's probably why they index each cell (makes it simple).

If, however, you KNOW the geometry, you can very likely optimize this WAY above the performance you're seeing.

If all you did was take out the src/dest derefence, you'd see SOME performance gain, as in:

```
        const size_t src_tda = src->tda ;
        const size_t dest_tda = dest->tda ;
        size_t i, j;

        float * dest_data = dest->data; // psuedocode here
        float * src_data  = src->data; // psuedocode here

        for (i = 0; i < src_size1 ; i++)
          {
            for (j = 0; j < MULTIPLICITY * src_size2; j++)
              {
                dest_data[MULTIPLICITY * dest_tda * i + j] 
                  = src_data[MULTIPLICITY * src_tda * i + j];
              }
          }
```

We'd HOPE the compiler recognized that anyway, but...sometimes...